# 16 bit image crashes Image.ThresholdBinary in EMGU.CV

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I have two versions of this app below.  This one, and a rewrite I wrote to work with 8 bit images.  8 bit images work fine.  16 bit images cause Image.Threshold to crash in the native OpenCV call for threshold, the only error returned:

A first chance exception of type 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
Additional information: OpenCV:

The below causes a crash on my "hand coded" 16 bit image, it also crashes on a 16 bit TIF image, loaded via

```
var img = new Image<Gray,UInt16>("test.tif");
```

The crashes are identical, with identical error messages.

Here's my app:

Thoughts?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace MyUnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTestOpenCV
    {
        // Set up an image with a solid rectangle in it.
        private IntPtr _smallImg;
        private const int Ncols = 500;
        private const int Nrows = 100;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Init()
        {
            const int n = Ncols * Nrows;
            var pixels = new short[n];
            _smallImg = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(n * 2);
            Marshal.Copy(pixels, 0, _smallImg, pixels.Length);
            for (int col = 75; col < 75 + 200; col++)
            {
                for (int row = 25; row < 25 + 50; row++)
                {
                    Marshal.WriteInt16(_smallImg, 2 * (row * Ncols + col), 10000);
                }
            }
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(_smallImg);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void FindingMinBoundingRectangle()
        {
            var img = new Image<Gray, ushort>(Ncols, Nrows, Ncols, _smallImg);
            var rotatedImg = img.Rotate(20, new Gray(0), false);
            var bwImg      = img.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(5000), new Gray(255));
            var contour    = bwImg.FindContours();
            var rect = contour.GetMinAreaRect();
            rotatedImg.Draw(rect, new Gray(30000), 50);
            rotatedImg.Save("img.tif");
            AOIAlgorithmsBase.SaveImage("myImg.tif", img.MIplImage.imageData, Ncols, Nrows, Ncols);
            ImageViewer.Show(rotatedImg, "Image Viewer Window");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ha you tried other values for Gray? Gray(5000) seems weird to me

Comment: My image has pixel values of 0 and 10,000.  I'm trying to create a binary image, so using 5,000 as the threshold.  My image is ushort, but Gray takes a double in as the constructor.  Does this mean EMGU is assuming a "double" image instead of ushort for Threshold?  Documentation says nothing.

Comment: Ha you tried displaying the image before applying tranformations? Does it show correctly?

Comment: Image DOES NOT display correctly, (i.e. using ImageViewer.Show) but that's because image is 16 bit, and ImageViewer appears to only work with 8 bit images.  I have dumped memory, and image looks fine.

Comment: Are you sure about this 8bits restriction? I would assume at this point that your image is not loaded correctly and transformations will fail because of that

Comment: Also images also have "stride" or alignment padding at the end of each line, you need to be aware of that if you are to fill your own buffers with data

Comment: I have the same code working fine with an 8 bit image, so yes, I'm certain it's a 16 bit image restriction.  I'm aware that there are alignment/stride issues, I believe I have addressed those correctly.  If there's a way to test that assertion, that'd be cool.

Comment: I'd try to load an image with the same dimensions and check the buffer content, compare it to what you have. Alignment may change with 16 bits

Comment: I have loaded 16 bit image from a file.  There's one pixel, every 32 bits in the machine.  The data loaded is correct.  This fails, and my hand "packed" version above fails as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually even if EmguCV reads 16-bit images, most processing routines require 8-bit or 32-bit images. From [OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold) for the threshold method:

> Parameters:
>   src – input array (single-channel, 8-bit or 32-bit floating point).

In my case, in convert my images to 8-bit for all the Emgu processing and displaying, and I convert back to 16-bit for saving in tif format.